# Visual Studio NUnit tests are not running

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, mvvmcross

We have an issue with our unit tests.  At some point, hitting "Run All" started giving us a truncated subset of tests that ran.  The others were simply not run, and we have been having to manually run groups and individual tests.

Any recommendations from anyone out there?

Update:

Partial Solve!

So, my first question was early on in my investigation. I had looked for previous solutions and hadn't found anything that worked out.

Some additional details...

This is an Android project using Xamarin and MvvmCross. The problem was a call to .Clear() on an MvxObservableCollection. Apparently the test just wasn't set up properly, and the IoC provider wasn't able to resolve an interface. I solved it temporarily by removing the call to the offending method.

My question now is how to set this up properly. We have a base test class that we are inheriting from MvxIoCSupportingTest, and the required components seem to have been set up correctly, but we were still experiencing this issue. How do we set up our tests so we can use the .Clear and other MvxObservableCollection methods?

Comment: Which VS version are you using? Have you upgraded to the VS Test SDK for that version? If you use a Preview versions you need to upgrade to a matching SDK version

Comment: BTW there are a *lot* of similar SO questions with answers that cover eg missing runners, incompatible SDK versions etc. Have you tried searching?

Comment: I have tried searching and have not found much...it's possible that my search terms were ineffective.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.4.4
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.4.4+29728.190
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03752

Installed Version: Professional

Comment: If you search for `visual studio nunit tests not running` you'll get 300 results. Using the wrong Test SDK affects all unit testing frameworks, eg xUnit and all recent VS versions